# Differences between sheaf and bundle

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

In Mathematics, particularly in Algebraic Geometry, the words *bundle* and *sheaf* are used everywhere in the literature to represent different concepts. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/) defines these two words as follows:

> **Sheaf:** a number of things, especially pieces of paper or plant stems, that are held or tied together.
>
> **Bundle:** a number of things that have been fastened or are held together.

Furthermore, it gives *bundle* as a synonym. In my native language (Spanish), there is however a difference between these two words, as one would say that a sheaf is *smaller* than a bundle. Also, in Spanish, the word for sheaf (*gavilla*) is used exclusively for stems or branches, such as vine shoots, that is, nobody would say *"una gavilla de papeles"*.

My question is if, despite the synonymity between bundle and sheaf mentioned in the Cambridge Dictionary, there exist more subtle differences between these two words.

Comment: 'Sheaf' is probably rarely used outside the old-fashioned usage for wheat and other plant stems, and the paper usage. 'Bundle' is more general, for say old clothes, rags, twigs ... and metaphorically nerves, rights, joy, cheer.... There isn't a size differential, though 'bundle' can be more amorphous than 'sheaf'.

Comment: Is there any distinction in the mathematical usage?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you could say every sheaf is a bundle but not every bundle is a sheaf, and that sheaf is more appropriate for agricultural terms?

Comment: @rajah9 There is definitely a relation, as a (fiber) bundle gives rise to a sheaf (of sections), but these terms cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: There are some contexts (farming, printing) where there are distinctions, but in general use they mean the same thing (though sheaf is less common).  And I'm not aware of any established use of either in mathematics.

Comment: Note that the terms "tree" and "branch" are used in math/science when referring to a tree-shaped graph.

Comment: Is a sheaf usually a gathering of the same type of things (all items are wheat or all items are paper), whereas a bundle could be dissimilar items? Maybe it's the arrangement of those items too? in a sheaf maybe they are all laid the same way, but a bundle can be higgledepiggledy?

Comment: I'd not risk using 'every X is a Y'; 'a sheaf of arrows' is a specific usage for a quiver-full.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mathematical usage, but I agree with @Smock that a sheaf  consists of straight things all lying in the same direction, while a bundle may be gathered together anyhow (like [the classic image](https://www.giantbomb.com/humble-bundle/3015-6612/))

Comment: Possibly another difference is maybe a sheaf is tied around the common axis, whereas a bundle is more of a wrapping up the whole thing? (like in the picture @KateBunting links)

Comment: Gingerly stepping into a Google search for "algebraic geometry bundle example" and "algebraic geometry sheaf example". Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics) made my brain hurt. They have a picture of a fiber bundle with a cylindrical hairbrush. They call a sheaf a presheaf that obeys the axioms locality and bundling.

Comment: **Bundle up**, it’s cold outside.

Comment: To me a sheaf is rather more loosely fastened than a bundle. A sheaf of grain, for instance, is tied only around the middle while a bundle of cloth or clothes is usually tied in at least two directions with the strings crossing in the middle. I also think of a bundle of papers as being securely tied, possibly with crossed strings whereas a sheaf of papers can be carried in one hand, often with no securing string.

Answer (score 1):

The words are used in a technical sense in mathematics. Their usage in that context does not need to, and in fact does not, bear any relation to their usage in other contexts. 
The Cambridge Dictionary is unlikely to be the prime source for the technical meaning of such words in mathematics.

As an academic in the mathematical world, I wish that my colleagues would cease to steal normal words and give them technical meanings unrelated to their normal meanings, but nothing I say will ever persuade them to stop.